# Change DOM element class based on text content of another element when generated by Jinja for loop

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I need to alter the colour of an HTML element based on the text content of another element. However, the content is being generated with a Python for loop using a Jinja shortcut.

For example:

```
{% for article in articles %}
    <div class="row article">
        <div class="col s6">
          <strong>{{ article.title }}</strong>
          <p>Page count: {{ article.page_count }}</p>
          <p>Layout code: <span id="layout">{{ article.layout }}</span></p>
        </div>
           <div id="show_layout" class="col s1 layout"></div>
        </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

I'm trying to use Javascript or jQuery to make the #show_layout element red if a layout code is present (ie. there is some text content in that span). The trouble is that I'm only able to make all or none show up red as the JS function runs once and affects every iteration of the for loop. For example, if 3 article listings are generated by the for loop (pulled from MongoDB) then each of the #show_layout elements turn red, if just one has any layout code content. I've tried experimenting with using the 'this' keyword, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Currently this is the basic function I'm altering, though there have been many different versions! I'm calling this on page load; calling it from the element itself doesn't seem to do anything!

```
    function showLayout() {
        let code = document.getElementById("layout").textContent;
        let toChange = document.getElementById("show_layout");
        if (code !== "") {
            toChange.classList.add("layout-red");
        console.log(code)
    }
    else {
        console.log("arghghg")
    }
}
```

I'm very new to Python and Jinja, so perhaps my approach is entirely wrong. Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Why do you want to do this using JavaScript? Jinja surely has conditional tags for if/else, and a way to check whether a variable is empty or not …

Comment: Just the direction I needed :) I did not know that!

Comment: This totally solved my problem  - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

CBroe pointed me in the right direction here, by suggesting that I do this via Jinja, which had not occurred to me (I'm very, very new to Jinja!).

adding:

```
        {% if article.layout != "" %}
        <div id="show_layout" class="col s1 layout-red show_layout"></div>
        {% endif %}
```

did the trick!

Thank you CBroe!